# cannot give reason for checkThat method in ErrorCollector class Junit

Tags: java, junit4

I am getting compilation errors when I try to give reason in case the matcher doesn't match value.

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

@Test
public void textShouldMatch(){
    String expected ="Lebron James";
    String result ="Kobe Bryant";
    collector.checkThat("Doesn't match",result, is(expected));
    }
```

The javadoc has the following syntax for checkThat method:

```
checkThat

public <T> void checkThat(String reason,T value, Matcher<T> matcher)
```

Adds a failure with the given reason to the table if matcher does not match value. Execution continues, but the test will fail at the end if the match fails.

Comment: Can you provide the signature of is() ?

Comment: String> Matcher<String> org.hamcrest.Matchers.is(String value)


This is a shortcut to the frequently used is(equalTo(x)). eg. assertThat(cheese, is(equalTo(smelly))) vs assertThat(cheese, is(smelly))

Comment: Could you also provide the compiler error?

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method checkThat(T, Matcher<T>) in the type ErrorCollector is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, Matcher<String>) but if you go to http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html